# How to show only commands I add in External Tools?

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm 2021.1.4 I added command in External Tools :

[image]

but clicking double <kbd>Shift</kbd> I see a lot of items (I set only Actions in filter):

[image]

How can I see only commands I add in External Tools?

Comment: Try switching to `Actions` tab (also accessible directly via `Help | Find Action...` -- Ctrl+Shift+A on Windows keymap) -- it **should** list such actions on top there (but it will not be the only thing though...)

Comment: You may also execute different commands via Double `Ctrl` (or `Tools | Run Command...`) You may need Command Line Tool Support plugin for that (bundled one). Commands executed there should be remembered so you can select it from your past history / drop down list.